# sprintf not working correctly - causing access violation

Tags: c++

I am using sprintf() however, I am getting an Access Violation error;

This error only occurs when the content of the string only contains 3 or less ints. (displayed below)

This is a method which reads in ints from a txt file and then sorts them;

```
string getIntsFromFile() {

ifstream myfile("/pathToFile/file.txt");
vector<int> values;
int value = 0;
string testString;

while (!myfile.eof())
{
    myfile >> value;

    if (myfile.eof()) break;

    values.push_back(value);
}

sort(values.begin(), values.end(), greater<int>());

for (int i = 0; i < values.size(); i++)
    testString = testString + to_string(values[i]) + "\n";
return testString;
}
```

Then I call this function using;

`char myString[128];

sprintf(myString, "%s", getIntsFromFile());`

This only works if there are more than 3 ints in the txt file but any less prompt an Access Violation error.

The ints in the txt file are seperated by a '\n', so there is only one int on each line.

Comment: You should provide actual code, not what you remember. I doubt `sprintf(myString, "%s", getIntsFromFile());` would compile. Provide MCVE

Comment: `while (!myfile.eof())` is wrong. Use `while (myfile >> value)`

Comment: `sprintf` with "%s" format specifier expects a `char*` argument. `getIntsFromFile()` returns an `std::string`. Try `getIntsFromFile().c_str()`.

Comment: A reasonable compiler would have warned you about that format string.

Comment: Since you are using `std::string` you should consider using `std::ostringstream` instead of `sprintf`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`sprintf`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fprintf) with `"%s"` format specifier expects a `char*` argument. `getIntsFromFile()` on the other hand returns an `std::string`. The behavior is undefined (which in your case you can observe as an access violation) in case the argument type does not match the expected type .

To confirm this, you can try

```
sprintf(myString, "%s", getIntsFromFile().c_str());
```

instead.

Note however, that this is also likely to fail as the number of integers increases and the string exceeds the allocated size of the `myString` buffer.

Comment: That worked a treat! Thanks for that much appreciated!

Could you tell me why it worked without the `c_str()` when the file had more than 3 ints but not when it had less?

Comment: such are the ways of _undefined behavior_. It is generally impossible to tell exactly what could happen (including the _appearance_ of something working) without the exact input, exact compiled instructions, and possibly exact memory content at the moment of execution.

Answer (score 2):

Either use `c_str()` method on string or use `std::copy()` method for this purpose.